# Check whether form is submitted or not

Tags: jquery

In my webpage a form is there with submit button (id = search) and predict button(id = predict). If user doesn't submit form, but clicks predict button it must alert form is not submitted. How to check whether form is submitted or not in JQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
       $('#Predict').click(function(){
         if($('#search').submit()) {            
             window.open("ouput.php");

          }

      else {  
        alert("Please click search or upload button first \n\
             and then click Predict "); 
         }
    });
});
```

But alert box is not appearing and also even if form is not submitted ouput.php page is opening.

Comment: Use .submit() on the form to check, whether is submited.

Comment: make that predict button to input type button(type="button") and search button to input type submit(type="submit"), now only the search button will submit form. And you can alert any message on predict click with any check.

Comment: I have already made my search button type to submit but my code is not working. @Rex

Comment: I have used .submit() function only but it is not working. Anything wrong in my code @WilfredoP

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand correctly your question and if this will help you
But in this page you have a form, when you submit the form the script add a class ok to predict button.
When you click on predict button the script chcks the presence of ok class
if the scripts does not find that class an alert message show up

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#a').submit(function(){
    $('#predict').addClass('ok') 
    })
  $('#predict').click(function(){
    var clas=$(this).attr('class')  
    if(clas!=='ok'){
        alert('you must submit the form')
    }
  })
})
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="a" action="#">
    <input type="text" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="summit" id="search">
    <input type="button" value="predict" id="predict">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```